# Is there a Wait() or Sleep() function in CAPL?

Tags: timer, wait, sleep, capl

I'm totally new to CAPL and I cannot find ANY good source for small questions on CAPL language. I went through the documentation and there is only mentions about wait() function either in XML or .Net syntax. Is there a function in CAPL itself that will do the wait() for me if I want to send a signal value every second for example? Can I do it with a Timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function. For wait, you must create a timer.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you. But how can I use it in a loop? For example I want to change a signal value every 1 second. For some reason I get errors when I put the "setTimer" and "on timer" in a for loop.

Comment: Got it, thanks to http://wenku.baidu.com/view/b28750c14028915f804dc2c4.html
I needed to put a setTimer in onStart and another setTimer in onTimer. Then onTimer becomes the body of my loop, I put all my signal changes there.

Answer (score 1):

Since CANoe 5.0 there is the function

```
long TestWaitForTimeout(dword aTimeout);
```

that can be used in Test Modules.

The argument is the maximum time that should be waited in milliseconds. 0 results in the test module waiting indefinitely.

The return values:

- -2: Resume due to constraint violation
- -1: General error, for example, functionality is not available
- 0: Resume due to timeout